# Meaning of "had a horror of destroying documents" in the Sherlock Holmes story "The Musgrave Ritual"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

In the Sherlock Holmes story "[The Musgrave Ritual](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/834/834-h/834-h.htm#link2H_4_0005)," Watson is describing the untidy nature of Sherlock Holmes. The description includes this sentence:

> He had **a horror of destroying documents**, especially those which were connected with his past cases,...

On first reading the phrase, I took "had a horror of destroying documents" to mean that Holmes *had a horrible habit of destroying documents*, horrible (or horrifying) to Watson in the sense that he wishes to chronicle the cases that Holmes has been involved in (and perhaps also horrifying in the sense that the documents might contain important evidence in ongoing police investigations). But the rest of the passage immediately makes it clear that Holmes does *not* destroy the documents:

> ...and yet it was only once in every year or two that he would muster energy to docket and arrange them...
>   ...month after month his papers accumulated, until every corner of the room was stacked with bundles of manuscript which were on no account to be burned, and which could not be put away save by their owner."

So after it becomes clear that Holmes is being a packrat rather than destroying anything, I take "a horror of" here to simply be a more concise way of saying "a shocking/absurd number of" documents.

That leaves me with the question of what "destroying documents" means in this context. Searches for the phrase are fruitless, as the Google waters are muddied with other instances of the phrase that mean, well, exactly what you would expect (incinerating documents or rending them into teeny tiny pieces), and corpora likewise only show instances of the literal, expected meaning.

I have some theories, the first one being most likely in my mind:

- "Destroying documents" is synonymous with "damning evidence" (i.e. Holmes has valuable information relevant to criminal investigations scattered haphazardly around his apartment).
- "Destroying documents" means "documents that are either of no use or contain sensitive information and should be destroyed" (unlikely).
- (updated) "Destroying documents" means the documents are slowly *being destroyed* by wear and tear because they are not stored properly.
- "Destroying documents" is a collocation from Sir Arthur Conan Doyle's time with some other specific meaning that has fallen out of use.

What does "destroying documents" mean in this context? "Damning evidence," "documents that should be destroyed," or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding of "had a horror of" rather than "destroying documents," which is the phrase the question focuses on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A horror of* is similar to *a great aversion to*.

I have an aversion to exercise = I don't like to exercise. I have a horror of exercise = I really really don't like to exercise.

*Destroying documents* is to be taken in the straightforward, literal sense: Mr Holmes really really dislikes or does not like to or does not want to destroy documents. He has 'a horror of' destroying documents. He wants to preserve them all and not destroy any.

Two other ways to express the same thing, that include words related to *horror*, are

*He abhors destroying documents*,  and

*He has an abhorrence of destroying documents.*

Comment: Ugh... I had to fight the urge to smack myself in the forehead after reading this. So obvious now that I was misunderstanding the meaning of "horror" and went off on a mental tangent trying to figure out "destroying documents." Anyway, thanks for the quick, clear answer.

Comment: I'm gonna leave the question up for posterity's sake, but I suspect it's going to be closed since my question is based on my misunderstanding of "a horror of" (and astounding failure to parse the phrase properly).

Comment: No problem. Just glad I could help.